# How to Drive a 5V relay?

Tags: relay

[image: circuit diagram]

I tried throwing together a little circuit that has an IR sensor (the Vsignal should really be a photodiode going to the supply) and switches the output high until C1 charges back up again. The Vout is supposed to apply high voltage to the input of a power relay (one of these [this](http://old.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/20084141716341001RelayX1.pdf)).

The circuit works perfectly fine *without* the relay output load (the output goes high until M3 is shut off again). However, with the relay hooked up to Vout, the voltage doesn't go back down even when Vgs of M3 is 0! Can someone explain why this is happening?

I quickly tried buffering the output with an emitter follower but it only partially allowed the voltage on Vout to drop down to about 2 or 3V.

Thanks

Comment: What is Vdd's voltage value? If Vdd=5V and your relay's coil is rated for 5V, then eliminate (remove) resistors R5 and R6 and connect the relay's coil between M3's drain and ground. Be sure to put a "snubber" diode (a.k.a., flyback diode) across the relay's coil to protect M3 from the coil's inductive kick (large voltage spike) that occurs when M3 turns OFF. For what it's worth, I'd consider adding a comparator with hysteresis to sense the voltage across C1, and use the comparator's "digital" output signal to drive the gate of M3 (rather than driving M3's gate directly from C1's voltage).

Comment: Vdd is 9V, though the relay's coil is rated for 5V. Is the inductive spike what's keeping the voltage high on M3, in the circuit I currently have? Shouldn't it discharge eventually through R6?

Comment: Can you provide the relay's part number? At this point it would help to know the manufacturer's specs for the relay's coil.

Comment: "Is the inductive spike what's keeping the voltage high on M3, in the circuit I currently have?" No. When M3 turns ON, current passes through the coil and builds up a field of stored energy (magnetic flux) around the coil. When M3 turns OFF, the magnetic flux around the coil collapses very quickly, thereby inducing a very large voltage spike across the coil whose amplitude can reach hundreds (or in some cases thousands of volts). (Think of a coil-based sparkplug ignition system in older cars.) This voltage spike can easily destroy MOSFET M3.